# Showing that vector field $X$ defined by $X_p := \widehat{\omega_p}^{-1}(\alpha_p)$ is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

This is exercise 1, p.22 in the book *Lectures on Symplectic Geometry* by *Ana Cannas da Silva*.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\alpha \in \Omega^{1}(M)$ such that
>   $\omega = -d\alpha$. Then there exists a unique vector field $X \in
> \mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that the interior multiplication of $X$ with
>   $\omega$ is $-\alpha$, i.e. $i_X\omega = -\alpha$.

Uniqueness is clear from the fact that $\widehat{\omega_p} : T_pM \to T^*_pM$ defined by $\widehat{\omega_p}(v) := \omega_p(v,\cdot)$ is an isomorphism due to the symplectic structure.

Existence. Let $p \in M$. Then we have to solve $i_X\omega = -\alpha$ which is equivalent to $\widehat{\omega_p}(X_p) = -\alpha_p$ or $$X_p = -\widehat{\omega_p}^{-1}(\alpha_p)$$ So left to show is that $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. Does anyone see why the mapping $p \mapsto X_p$ is smooth?

**Edit.** One can check that $\widehat{\omega}: TM \to T^*M$ is a smooth bundle isomorphism. Hence we define $$X := -\widehat{\omega}^{-1}(\alpha).$$ Let us check that $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. Clearly, $X$ is a section by definition of $\widehat{\omega}$ and furthermore smooth since it is the composition of smooth mappings.

Comment: Isn't the mapping $\widehat\omega\colon TM\to T^*M$ smooth?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you! Yes, it is the tangent-cotangent bundle isomorphism. Stupid me.

Comment: Not a matter of stupidity. And, although I haven't read it for correctness, it appears @Jakob checked it explicitly using Darboux coordinates.

Comment: @TedShifrin I did the same thing. But somehow I am not sure about that approach. I think I solved it thanks to you: define $X := -\widehat{\omega}^{-1}(\alpha)$ which is mooth (see edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way to prove this. But you could just apply Darboux's theorem and get coordinates $(p^i, q^i )$ around any point such that
$$\omega = \sum_i \mathrm d q^i \wedge \mathrm d p^i$$
in that coordinate neighborhood. In that case, $$X = \sum_i (X^{p^i} \partial_{p^i} + X^{q^i} \partial_{q^i})$$ (analogous for a vector field Y which I'm going to use in a blink of an eye) and
$$i_{X} \omega (Y) = \sum_i X^{p^i} i_{\partial_{p^i}} (\sum_j \mathrm dq^j \wedge \mathrm d p^j )(Y) + \sum_i X^{q^i} i_{\partial_{q^i}} (\sum_j \mathrm dq^j \wedge \mathrm d p^j )(Y) = \dots = \sum_i (- X^{p^i} Y^{q^i} + X^{q^i} Y^{p^i}) \stackrel{!}{=} \sum_i (\alpha_{p^i} Y^{p^i} + \alpha_{q^i} Y^{q^i})$$
But from that you can infer that $$X= \sum_i (\alpha_{p^i} \partial_{q^i} - \alpha_{q^i} \partial_{p^i})$$

The components are obviously smooth functions of the coordinates, hence this vector field is smooth.

This is independent of the condition that $\mathrm d \alpha = - \omega$. It's a general fact that a symplectic form turns smooth 1-forms into smooth vector fields and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you, Jakob. I did the same thing, but I have some issues (the things you did are correct, so clearly +1): The task is to find a vector field $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, so a global vector field. We only do have a description in charts. I mean: How would we define a global vector field with this local data?