# Show that $g_*X = X$ for a symplectomorphism $g$ (Lectures on Symplectic Geometry Exercise)

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

This is again exercise 1, p. 22 from *Lectures on Symplectic Geometry* by *Ana Cannas da Silva*.

> Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $\alpha \in \Omega^1(M)$
>   such that $\omega = -d\alpha$. Furthermore let $g: M  \to M$ be a
>   symplectomorphism which preserves $\alpha$, i.e. $g^{*}\alpha =
> \alpha$. Show that $$g_* X = X$$ where $X$ is the unique vector field
>   such that $i_X\omega = -\alpha$.

From my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406305/showing-that-vector-field-x-defined-by-x-p-widehat-omega-p-1-alpha/2406313#2406313), we get that $X = -\widehat{\omega}^{-1}(\alpha)$, where $\widehat{\omega} : TM \to T^*M$ is defined by $(p,v_p) \mapsto \omega_p(v_p,\cdot)$. Has anyone a hint for me how to show that $g_*X = X$? I mean we have that $$(g_* X)_{g(p)} = dg_p(X_p)$$ But I am not sure how to proceed. I guess I have to use that $g$ is a symplectormorphism and that it preserves $\alpha$, but I am not sure how to use this. Also I am a bit confused by $\omega = -d\alpha$, since until now I did not use this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note $g^*\alpha=\alpha$ and $\omega = -d\alpha$ implies $g^* \omega = \omega$. Then for any $Y$,

$$\begin{split}
\omega (g_* X,Y) &= (g^* \omega) (X, g^{-1}_* Y) \\
&= \omega(X, g^{-1}_* Y) \\
&= \iota_X \omega (g^{-1}_* Y) \\
&=-\alpha (g^{-1}_* Y) \\
&= -((g^{-1})^* \alpha)(Y) \\
&=-\alpha(Y) \\
&= \iota_X \omega (Y) \\
&= \omega (X, Y). 
\end{split}$$

Since $Y$ is arbitrary and $\omega$ is nondegenerate, $X = g_*X$.

Comment: Just one question: From where does the first equality come from?

Comment: That's the definition of $g^*$, which is $g^*\omega (X, Y) = \omega(g_* X, g_* Y)$. @TheGeekGreek

Comment: Sorry, I use the definition provided in Lee. Then I get that $g^*\omega(X,Y) = \omega(g_*X,g_*Y) \circ g$ since $$\begin{align*}
F^*A(X_1,\dots,X_k)(p) &= (F^*A)_p(X_1\vert_p,\dots,X_k\vert_p)\\
&= A_{F(p)}(d F_p(X_1\vert_p),\dots,d F_p(X_k\vert_p))\\
&= A_{F(p)}((F_*X_1)_{F(p)},\dots,(F_*X_k)_{F(p)})\\
&= A(F_*X_1,\dots,F_*X_k
)(F(p)).
\end{align*}$$ for a diffeomorphism $F : M \to N$ and a $k$-covector field $A$. Your proof works fine also with this, but maybe you could say something about the missing composition with $g$, perhaps I do oversee something.